# Converting BufferedReader to JSONObject or Map

Tags: java, json, dictionary, httprequest

My code sends a GET request to a server,

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

I get a BufferedReader object that prints,

```
{  
   "status": "ERROR",    
   "errorCode": "MISSING_PARAMS",    
   "errorMessage": null,    
   "requestId": "20141014181739_11625805172",    
   "downstreamModuleErrorCode": null,    
   "object": [        
     "activity_code",        
     "activity_name",
     "points",
     "frequency",
     "strategy",
     "vsa_app_access_token"    
   ]
}
```

I want to get a JSONOBject or a Map from this. I tried converting this into a String and manipulating it. But it's not that easy to do. Please help.

Comment: check my answer. Its explained and working.

Comment: I used this llibrary,
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/
you can do like this:
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(in.toString()));
JsonObject jsonObj=jsonReader.readObject();

Comment: javaee librarys in a java se project? try using a proper library which fits your needs like the one ive written above

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First do it as string. you can use custom librarys for that like

```
 String message = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(rd);
```

or a StringBuilder

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
```

Then you can parse it. Since it's an object because of the "{" (array begin and ends with []) you need to create an JSONObject.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

then you can access your elements with

```
//{ "status": "ERROR", "errorCode": "MISSING_PARAMS", "errorMessage": null, "requestId": "20141014181739_11625805172", "downstreamModuleErrorCode": null, "object": [ "activity_code", "activity_name", "points", "frequency", "strategy", "vsa_app_access_token" ]}

json.getString("status");
```

or the array with

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("object"));
```

or you use the method getJSONArray()

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("object");
```

Comment: I get an error saying:
The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined

Comment: You need org.json. Get it with maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json or download the library/code by github. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Answer (score 5):

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line + "\n");
        }

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if (!json.get("object").equals(null)) {
        JSONArray objectJsonArray = json.getJSONArray("object");
            for (int i = 0; i < objectJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = objectJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);     
            }       
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: why do you copy and paste a code which does not fit the solution?

Answer (score 1):

And what about this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(in);
JsonObject object = reader.readObject();
String s = object.toString();
```

Comment: Can't seem to find Json.createReader

Comment: @CamHart Taken directly from oracle docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html

Comment: not for android

Answer (score 0):

Using this lib (org.json) you can convert strings to json objects: http://www.json.org/java/

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of `org.json`, you can do:

```java
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(bufferedReader);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

As a quick proof, this works with `org.json:json:20190722`:

```java
byte[] b = "{ \"active\" : true }".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(bufferedReader);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
```